Firebase Auth JS SDK Error instantiating RecaptchaVerifier object
Im trying to implement phone authentication in a react native app using Firebase Javascript SDK (v10.12.2) and Im getting the following error while trying to instantiate a RecaptchaVerifier object:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined, js engine: hermes

And here is the respective code:
const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(getAuth(), 'recaptcha-container', {
  size: 'invisible',
});

The captcha container exists in a View element with ID "recaptcha-container":
<View id="recaptcha-container"></View>

I also tried to disable app verification for testing like this, but without effect: getAuth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
Any help would be much appreciated!

Same here. The docs are trash.
